# Turn array value into array key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$array = ('mango','apple','orange','peach');
```

I want to turn it into a new variable like this:

```
$options = ('mango'=>'mango','apple'=>'apple','orange'=>'orange','peach'=>'peach');
```

basically I want to make the array value become the array key, i can achieve it with a loop like this:

```
foreach($array as $value){
  $options[$value] = $value; 
}
```

but is there any native PHP function or one-liner function that acts the same way as the above function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_combine()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php:

```php
$options = array_combine($array, $array);
```

You should probably make sure array contains only unique values first using `array_unique()` to avoid key conflicts.